# Add category selection to function request

Tags: posts, categories, select

Got the following in my functions file, which is designed to query the last three posts published, however I want to limit it by a certain category.

I was looking at adding is_category to the WHERE declaration but it didnt seem to work.

```
$request = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type='post' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $no_posts";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a sql query, I recommend to do it in wordpress way:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts' => 3,
'offset' => 0,
'category' => put_your_category_id_here,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true );

$request = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
```

Reference : [WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts)

**Update** : here is the way to get thumbnail url when you have postid

```
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    if($post_thumbnail_id){
      $imageurl = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );
    }
```

answer to your last comment :

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ 
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . $recent["post_title"] . '">
    <article>';
      $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($recent["ID"]);
      if($post_thumbnail_id){
      $imageurl = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );
      echo '<img src="' . $imageurl . '" alt="" class="latest-img" >';
      }
      echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/g.png" class="g" width="667" height="266">
      <div class="latest-meta">
        <time class="hstack white">DATE</time>
        <h2 class="white gstack">' . $recent["post_title"] . '</h2>
      </div>
    </article>
    </a>';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried to implement this as it looks cleaner/easy to understand.

How would I get that request to output '$posts = $request' ?

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to ask? ... if you loop using foreach you can get everything from the posts in result.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't very clear. I've managed to get it working now using foreach - the only think I'm not sure is how to pull in the thumbnail URL. 

wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail)

Comment: I am adding it in answer. also, if you find answer helpful, you should accept it so that it helps others as well.

Comment: Thanks Gopal, this is really helpful. How would I add the above code you added to the foreach statement?

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
     echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . $recent["post_title"] . '"><article><img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail)  . '" alt="" class="latest-img" ><img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/g.png" class="g" width="667" height="266"><div class="latest-meta"><time class="hstack white">DATE</time><h2 class="white gstack">' . $recent["post_title"] . '</h2></div></article></a>';
     }